How to store the received data in the array from CAPL trace window
I need to achieve the following:
Periodically Send RX Messages:
I am sending RX messages periodically in CAPL.
Receive Messages:
When these messages are received, they appear in the trace window.
Store Received Data:
I want to store the received CAN message data (which is an 8-byte frame) into an array for further processing.
Data Structure:
The data includes message IDs and 8-byte frames.
How can I implement CAPL code to store the received 8-byte data from CAN messages into an array?

Please show what you have coded so far. In general, the message id is in message.id, payload in message.byte
